# BubbleSort Algorithm with Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, bubble-sort

Trying to make a basic project which is going to get values from user and the values are going to be stored on an array. But the project is not succeed.

I want to fix the problem and make the project work successfully...

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding= ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.Al.setOnClickListener{
        val size=arr.size
        arr[count] = binding.editTextNumber.text.toString().toInt()
        count++
        bubbleSort(arr)
    }
    binding.Sirala.setOnClickListener {
        binding.textView.clearComposingText()
        for (i in arr){
            binding.textView2.append(" "+arr[i])
        }
    }
}



private fun bubbleSort(arr: IntArray): IntArray {
    val n = arr.size
    for (i in 0 until n - 1) {
        for (j in 0 until n - i - 1) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                val temp = arr[j]
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1]
                arr[j + 1] = temp
            }
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

and here is error that has been gotten on logcat.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                   Process: com.example.bubblesortproject, PID: 21678
                                                                                                java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=23
                                                                                                    at com.example.bubblesortproject.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$1(MainActivity.kt:31)
                                                                                                    at com.example.bubblesortproject.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$FXYwObaoJg4LXbp8X8Ms3P8Tc24(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                    at com.example.bubblesortproject.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: What's the problem you're encountering?

Comment: datas are not stored regularly when getting(Al) button is clicked and the second problem is array is not showed in the textview that I have expected.  The array is showed as 0 0 0 0 0 and no more.

Comment: That's an indexOutOfBounds. This means you are trying to loop through an array which size is less then the indexes you are using.

Comment: But the size of array is 5 and user enters nothing but 5 inputs.

Comment: I think you have a problem with j and j+1. When the size is 2 your j can get the value 0 and 1. Also, when you use arr[j + 1](j  = 1), the array size doesn't have enough elements. Review your code.

Comment: In `onCreate` you iterate `for (i in arr)` and then access `arr[i]`, which doesn't make sense. You should look at the type of exception the logs showed you (first line) and where it occurred (second line) to understand the error.

Comment: the main problem have been fixed but now There is no showed number in the textview. The program is showing only addresses. Also I am not be able to see any error in the logs.